# Information not been recorded properly using php

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-update

My script lock like this example.

```
$variable1 = $POST['field1'];
$variable2 = $POST['field2'];
$variable3 = $POST['field3'];

$sql11 = "UPDATE ....
.......$variable1.............
$sql12 = "UPDATE ....
.......$variable1.............
$sql13 = "UPDATE ....
.......$variable1.............

$sql21 = "UPDATE ....
.......$variable2.............
$sql22 = "UPDATE ....
.......$variable2.............
$sql23 = "UPDATE ....
.......$variable2.............

$sql31 = "UPDATE ....
.......$variable3.............
$sql32 = "UPDATE ....
.......$variable3.............
$sql33 = "UPDATE ....
.......$variable3.............

sqlsrv_query($conn, sql11);
sqlsrv_query($conn, sql12);
sqlsrv_query($conn, sql13);
sqlsrv_query($conn, sql21);
sqlsrv_query($conn, sql22);
sqlsrv_query($conn, sql23);
sqlsrv_query($conn, sql31);
sqlsrv_query($conn, sql32);
sqlsrv_query($conn, sql33);

header ("Location: http:file.php");
```

And sometimes last query's are not been effected. Why? Can the problem be because the script is too long? and file are redirected to file.php before finish writing? All update statements are correct. How to solve? For loop is good idea?

Comment: I can't help you on the php side but you should NEVER build an update like that using input from the user. This is a textbook definition of sql injection. Use parameterized queries or stored procs.

Comment: Thanks but sql injections next step when i solve all logic problems

Comment: Interesting approach. I would write my code from the get go to avoid such issues. Who knows, when you write it that way maybe you will fix the other issue. Hope you figure it out.